# ¿Cómo hacer la espera a las solicitudes de un Ajax dentro de otro?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

Estoy tratando de crear un sistema de verificación de dispositivos conectados en red por medio de `ICMP` (ping). Todo el trabajo con respecto a la verificación lo hace `PHP` (Funcional). Inicialmente lo que hago con la aplicación es mostrar los registros que simulan ser los dispositivos (dirección ip). Luego con un elemento tipo `button` capturo el evento `click` y hago una solicitud `ajax`, que manda a traer los registros de dispositivos del gestor de base de datos; estos datos los extraigo en un objeto `JSON`.

Código PHP (`gn.TestingShowUsers.php`):

```
<?php
    @session_start();
    #Importar constantes.
    include (@$_SESSION['getConsts']);
    include (PF_CONNECT_SERVER);
    include (PF_SSH);

    $CN = new ConnectSSH();
    $CN->ConnectDB($H, $U, $P, $D, $X);

    $R = $CN->getHostWithOutInterfaces();
    #Esto es lo importante...
    $jsondata = array();

    if ($R->num_rows > 0){
           $jsondata["success"] = true;
           $jsondata["data"]["message"] = sprintf("Se han encontrado %d registros", $R->num_rows);
           $jsondata["data"]["hosts"] = array();
           while ($row = $R->fetch_object())
               $jsondata["data"]["hosts"][] = $row;
    } else {
        $jsondata["success"] = false;
        $jsondata["data"] = array(
                "message" => "No se encontraron resultados"
            );
    }
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($jsondata, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

    exit();
?>
```

Este código utiliza un par de clases para que todo funcione, lo muestro para que observen la estructura del `JSON`. La petición `Ajax` es la siguiente:

```
    var respuesta;
$("#TestingShowUsers").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "app/Desktop/Root/php/gn.TestingShowUsers.php", 
        type: "post", 
        dataType: "json",
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        respuesta = response;
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
         if ( console && console.log ) {
             console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
         }
    })
    .then(function(){
        if (respuesta.success){
            $.each(respuesta.data.hosts, function( key, value ) {
                //recorremos los valores de cada dispositivo
                $.each( value, function ( userkey, uservalue) {
                    if (userkey == "ip_host"){
                        //Este lo ocupo para seleccione a una clase que ya está automatizada para aplicarle cambios.
                        var ClassParent = uservalue.split(".").slice(0,4).join("");
                        var parametros = {
                            "ip_addr" : uservalue,
                        }
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "app/Desktop/Root/php/gn.CheckPing.php",
                            type: "post",
                            data: parametros,
                            beforeSend: function() {
                                                                //Código para que el contenedor con la clase automatizada, cargue un loader antes de la ejecución de la petición.
                                NProgress.configure({ parent: '.host' + ClassParent });
                                NProgress.start();
                            }, 
                            success: function(data){
                                                                //Que el proceso del loader, deje de continuar porque ya está verificado.
                                NProgress.done();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Script (`gn.CheckPing.php`):

```
    <?php
    @session_start();
    #Importar constantes.
    include (@$_SESSION['getConsts']);
    include (PD_DESKTOP_ROOT_PHP_CLASS."/gn.class.ping.php");
    $CD = new CheckDevice();
    #El retorno es 1 o 0. Aunque no tiene importancia porque en JS de momento no hago la verificación.
    echo ($CD->ping($_POST['ip_addr'])) ? "1" : "0";
?>
```

El la solicitud al script: `gn.CheckPing.php` no se manda a llamar después del `.then.` Pero si luego doy otro click en el botón que vuelve a hacer las solicitudes, entonces sí es mandado a llamar, en este caso en el `JSON` he mostrado 3 registros, lo cual si manda a ejecutar 3 veces con sus respectivos parámetros, ahí todo bien.

**Problema:**
El código para cargar el `loader`, se ejecuta asíncronamente, lo cual corre de una sola vez sin esperar la respuesta de las solicitudes, ya que antes de la solicitud necesito mostrar el `loader` encima del contenedor que representa al dispositivo, luego de haber hecho la verificación, entonces pasaré al siguiente registro del objeto `JSON` para que haga lo mismo con los demás. Pero el ciclo `$.each` pasa de un solo toque, no espera que devuelva un resultado es por esa razón, cuando necesito que el primer contenedor del dispositivo presente el `loader`, lo está presentando en el último contenedor porque ya pasó por todos sin haber verificado.

Answer (score 2):

He resuelto el problema, aprendí sobre ejecución asíncrona con generadores, workers, promesas y corrutinas; totalmente un mundo que desconocía. Con esa idea de programación, logré enviar y recibir las peticiones al servidor en orden.

La solución es la siguiente:

```
function CheckPingAjax(value, callback) {
    console.log('START execution with value =', value);
    var ip_host = respuesta.data.hosts[value].ip_host;
    var parametros = {"ip_addr" : ip_host}

    NProgress.start();

    $.ajax({
        url: "app/Desktop/Root/php/gn.CheckPing.php",
        type: "post",
        data: parametros,
        success: function(data){
            NProgress.done();
            callback(value, {ip_host: ip_host, data: data});
        }
    });
}

function nuevallamada(){

    var max_host = respuesta.data.count;
    var i_host = 0;

    NProgress.configure({parent: '.host' + respuesta.data.hosts[i_host].ip_host.split(".").slice(0,4).join("")});
    CheckPingAjax(i_host, function callback(value, result) {


        console.log('END execution with value =', value, 'and result =', result.ip_host, ' and status: ', result.data);
        if (result.data == "1"){
            var request = ".host" + respuesta.data.hosts[i_host].ip_host.split(".").slice(0,4).join("");
            $(request).css("border-top", "3px solid blue");
        }

        if (i_host === max_host-1) {
            console.log('COMPLETED Principal');
            i_host = 0;
            NProgress.done();
        } else {
            // NProgress.start();
            if (i_host < max_host-1){
                NProgress.configure({parent: '.host' + respuesta.data.hosts[++i_host].ip_host.split(".").slice(0,4).join("")});
                CheckPingAjax(i_host, callback);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hola Jerson! me alegra que lo solucionaras. Por favor, explica un poco el funcionamiento de tu respuesta siguiendo [answer]. Y recuerda marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo